# Array of strings in C++ for parallelization

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I am transfering a project from Python to C++ and got stuck right at the beginning where I have to decide which data structure I should use. I have a database with millions of small data files that have names like `1986_12_04_23_43_34_458239_VpLGMI` (the names of the data files can vary in length and type). I want to load the file names into a data structure from where I can then search quickly for substrings in the file names.

Since I worked mostly with Python the last years I am not sure which approach I should take. There are many ways to store strings in arrays in C++. Right now I am counting three:

- The string class `std::string`
- The vector class `std::vector`
- 2D arrays

I guess 2D arrays are not a good choice since they are not really flexible. Which approach should I follow if I later want to parallelize the search?

Comment: `std::vector<std::string>` is where I would start and only change if after benchmarking it shows you have an issue.

Comment: The question really is: What do you use this data structure for exactly? "I can search for them quickly" By what criteria?

Comment: Also note that databases are pretty good at looking up things themselves.  It might be faster to just query the database for what you need then to load data from it and do it yourself.

Comment: @idmean I want to search for certain substrings. Like `find_str = "1986_12"`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Searching for substrings is an important detail that should be in the question, not a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first option should be `std::vector<std::string>` and thanks to [parallel algorithm](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/parallelism/existing) you can use parallel version of `find` for look up with O(N) complexity:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <execution>
#include <string>

std::vector<std::string> v;
std::string someString = "someName";
v.push_back(someString);
auto res = std::find(std::execution::par, 
 std::begin(v), std::end(v), someString);
// res is an iterator to an element of which
//has someString
```

You can improve the complexity by sorting the vector and then using [std::lower_bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound)(which uses binary search) instead of `std::find`.

Alternatively as @jjramsey suggested you can use std::set which store the strings in sorted form and has O( log N ) to search for an individual element or `std::unordered_set` with O(1) complexity. 
Similarly `std::map` and `std::unordered_map`.

In these containers you will pay some overhead up front for insertion though.

Be aware that that parallel version of algorithm require C++17. [Live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/EYg1h0cNuIdUFKbA)

Comment: This isn't really a good way to search *quickly*. That searches through `v` in O(`v.size()`) time. `std::set` or `std::unordered_set` would be better for the usage scenario that you describe.

Comment: @jjramsey you are right if the insertion wasn't costly. One has to benchmark and find which container is better for the use case the OP has.

Comment: What does `v` stand for? Is it a vector full of strings? What does the `auto` keyword stand for?

Comment: @Samuel I edited the code. Auto is for automatic deduction of the data type of an expression. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto

Comment: Your sample code does not compile on my machine. What do I have to change to use the GNU C++ compiler `g++`? The error message says `std::execution has not been declared`. Can I replace `auto` when I am not familiar with the term? How do I use the iterator `res`? How could I for example print the matches using `res`?

Comment: @Samuel I added the headers you need. If you don't want to use auto you can replace it with `std::vector<std::string>::iterator`

Comment: @Samuel you also need to compile with -std=c++17 flag.

Comment: @Samuel I added a live link too. seems only MSVC 2017 and g++ head has the implementation for the parallel version.

Comment: @Oblivion When I try to use `#include <execution>` I get the following error: `fatal error: execution: No such file or directory`. I use the g++ compiler version 8.3.0 and Linux.

Comment: @Samuel please check the live link. Only MSVC17 and g++ head has the implementation today. You have to use either of these compilers